# Less Obvious Times to Use Node.js Callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, asynccallback

I understand callbacks and that you'd want to use it to make functions like timers or lengthy calculations or database queries asynchronous. What are less obvious times/tasks/situations you'd want to use callbacks? Can you give any real world examples, preferably ones you/your team has experienced personally? Am I going about this thought process wrong?

Comment: I just realized my question acttually was directed to node. It's my understanding that node is single threaded so you want to make lengthy functions asynchrous as to not block operations. So going off that, lets say an obvious example of when to use an asynchronous function is having a lengthy calculation. I would want to make that asynchrous as so allow other functions to be done while waiting for that calculation to finish. So what I'm asking it what a less obvious scenario would be that somebody has encountered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not necessarily just used for asynchronous execution. The function that the callback is passed to may return synchronously, in which case the callback pattern must have been used for some other reason. For instance:

- To allow the function to applied to multiple sets of data, for instance an array
- When the value needed to be passed to the callback cannot be accessed outside of the function's scope

There are other ways to achieve asynchronous execution, for instance the promise pattern (here the function called returns an object that can register a callback, rather than having the callback passed directly to it), which is built into ES6. await / async functions have been proposed to be introduced to the ES7 spec. These features can be used today if you use a transpiler.

Answer (score 1):

Callbacks are used quite frequently with Arrays (and objects if you're using something like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) or [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)). They are also used a lot with functional programming in general.

- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Sort)
- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)